# Objectの組込みプロパティlengthを使用する際、Object.keysを使用しなければいけない理由は？

Tags: javascript

**Objectの組込みプロパティlengthはなぜ、obj.length;で使用できないのでしょうか？**
・常に1だから？
・対象はユーザ定義オブジェクトではないのでしょうか？

```
var obj = { k: 1 };
obj.length; //undefined
```

---

**Object.keysで取得できるということは、組込みプロパティlengthは列挙不可に設定されているのでしょうか？**

```
var obj = { k: 1 };
Object.keys(obj).length; //1
```

---

**in演算子で確認できると思ったのですが**
・in演算子は組込みプロパティには未対応なのでしょうか？

```
var obj = { k: 1 };
"length" in obj; //false


var obj = { k: 1 };
length in obj; //false
```

---

**組込みプロパティlengthは、どこに所属しているのでしょうか？**

```
var obj = { k: 1 };
obj.hasOwnProperty('length'); //false

var obj = { k: 1 };
obj.k.hasOwnProperty('length'); //false

var obj = { k: 1 };
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj); //["k"]
```

Comment: `Object.length` は１でもインスタンスにはlengthプロパティは存在しないと思います。 また`Object.keys(obj)` は、列挙可能なプロパティの配列です。配列はlengthプロパティを持ちます。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

最近JavaScript関連の規格の進歩には必ずしもついていけていないので、改めて調べてみたのですが、lengthを「Objectの組み込みプロパティ」とする記述は見つけられませんでした。いくつかの記述から判断すると、**「Objectのコンストラクタのlength」と「Objectのlength」を混同**されているように思われます。

***Objectの組込みプロパティlengthはなぜ、obj.length;で使用できないのでしょうか？***
Objectには組み込みプロパティとしてのlengthはないわけですから、当然obj.lengthは一般的には未定義です。Objectのコンストラクタのlengthプロパティは、当然`Object.length`で参照できてその値は1のはずです。

***Object.keysで取得できるということは、組込みプロパティlengthは列挙不可に設定されているのでしょうか？***
Object.keysはオブジェクトを連想配列として使用する場合のキーの配列(Array)を返します。Arrayにはlengthが定義されていますから、`Object.keys(obj).length`はArrayのlengthプロパティを参照しており、Objectのlengthプロパティが「列挙不可」かどうかとは直接の関係はありません。Arrayのlengthプロパティは列挙不可ではあります。

***in演算子で確認できると思ったのですが***
何度も述べていますが、Object一般にはlengthプロパティは必ずしも存在しませんから、in演算子で調べてもlengthプロパティの存在は確認できません。Objectのコンストラクにはlengthプロパティが存在するので、`'length' in Object`は`true`を返すはずです。

***組込みプロパティlengthは、どこに所属しているのでしょうか？***
Array, String, Functionなどに定義されています。JavaScriptのコンストラクタはFunctionの一種なので、「Objectのコンストラクタのlength」もFunctionのlengthと同じものです。